# validate unique email and mobile no in javascript node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to validate email and mobile uniquely by javascript callback code.
get data from sql query and then validate email and mobile uniquely that no one can registered existing email and mobile.

```js
var connection = require('./../config');
module.exports.register=function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
    let myemail=req.body.email;
    let myphone=req.body.mobile;
    var users={
        "name":req.body.name,
        "email":req.body.email,
        "mobile":req.body.mobile,
        "password":req.body.password
    } 
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 let validemail=re.test(myemail.toLowerCase());
 if(validemail==false)
 {
    res.json({
        status:false,
        message:'Please enter a valid email id.'
    })
 }

 else{



     connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email ='"+myemail+"'")  



     connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE mobile ='"+myphone+"'")

     
     

    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',users, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        //   console.log("Errr",error)
          if(error.sqlMessage=='Duplicate entry \''+users.mobile+'\' for key \'mobile\'')
          {
        
                res.json({
                    status:false,
                    message:users.mobile+' You are already registered with this mobile no!'
                })
          }
          else if(error.sqlMessage=='Duplicate entry \''+users.email+'\' for key \'email\'')
          {
        
                res.json({
                    status:false,
                    message:myemail+' You are already registered with this email address'
                })
          }
          else{
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
        })
    }
      }else{
          res.json({
            status:true,
            data:results,
            message:'user registered sucessfully'
        })
      }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You want to do it, so do it..

Comment: If you want someone to help you, start by helping them by explaining your problem further

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help to solve your problem

```
connection.query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE email=? OR phonenumber=?",(err,result){

    if(result.length){

        return console.log("Duplicate entry found");
    }
    /*--Handle insert query here--*/
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',users, function (error, results, fields) {
        //do the rest here
    });


})
```